# Do I really need an antivirus for my arch linux machine?

Tags: arch-linux, malware

I have an arch Linux machine and I use it quite often. Moreover, I have a lot of applications even applications from aur, so my question is do I need an antivirus for it?

Comment: Maybe. It depends on your use case and situation.

Comment: Do you use an antivirus on android or iOS? No? Then your Arch Linux is quite similar, it usually doesn't need an antivirus. But there are special cases where it might be a requirement. Just, please!!! don't install software from some random web page, just don't!!.

Comment: @gapsf do you also advocate driving without a seatbelt, because you (personally) have never had a car crash? There are reasons for needing antivirus and other forms of computer security. Saying "no, never" is a very dangerous position to take.

Comment: @gapsf No antivirus will prevent a zero-day; they are always behind by some time period. That said, the majority of the issues I see on a regular basis are exploits that are weeks to years old. Do you normally examine code from PyPi to make sure it doesn't have a malicious payload? Can most users recognize malicious code when it is present or should we trust some people whose business mode depends on this recognition? I assume the code vetting is routine for people who know how to work with computers safely. Is this required by your workflow before you ever install though pip/pecl/cpan/etc.?

Comment: If you ask the same question as asked on SU earlier: https://superuser.com/questions/1744367/do-i-really-need-an-antivirus-for-my-arch-linux-machine , please delete it on SU so it's not a cross-post.

Comment: Thank you @A.B for your advice

Comment: @A.B I can't delete it because the system is prohibiting me from because 2 people answered my question.

Comment: @gapsf some truly horrible advice there. I've dealt with PCs with over 70 different malware strains. The OP doesn't need an AV but for absolutely different reasons: there are no AVs for Linux (I'm not joking) - the ones which work under Linux are mostly capable of detecting Windows/Mac OS malware. AUR packages are created and maintained by God knows whom and may contains backdoors or malware. You never know.

Comment: Using AV is better than not using AV when someone has a powerful rig.

Comment: I will never ever possibly leave my mates without an AV for their Windows PCs. Luckily Microsoft added Windows Defender which is not bad. Its only shortcoming is that its virus DB is updated a lot less frequently than for other commercial AVs, some of which push updates as often as every 10 minutes. As for Linux, deal with this: https://itvision.altervista.org/linux-myths-series-linux-doesnt-need-an-antivirus.html

Answer (score 1):

If you obey good security practices (like not running things with sudo and updating your system often as you're on a rolling release distro), an antivirus is not "necessary".

It offers the advantage of detection of known ransomware and other threats statically, and potentially some dynamic analysis of risky network/disk behavior, and that is advantageous if your activities on the machine expose you directly to threats (ie torrenting, security work, or hosting any service that opens ports to the public). If you are just a typical personal-use user with an updated system, your chance of being targeted is virtually nil.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use genuine repos for downloading any tools or updating the system, as we are on the rolling edition there might be some random bugs that might be potentially vulnerable to many threats. So, best option is to keep backup of one or two old versions of tools, so that you can downgrade your tools or system on the fly if you find any bugs or potential threats.

And as @belkarx pointed, you must not run any of the external files or those files which might not seem genuine with super user permission; If however, you are good at programming, you can always check the scripts for the flow of the code and run with super permission as needed.

You may also find many useful information on different system hardening sites or blogs, like

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-security.html

https://linuxsecurity.com/features/must-read-articles/top-tips-for-securing-your-linux-system-in-2020

https://safecomputing.umich.edu/protect-yourself/secure-your-devices/personal-computer/linuxunix

As, far as I am concerned, I don't use any antivirus but I am always careful and investigate before running any scripts.